# How to activate the timer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, timer

I'm new in asp.net. Im develping a web-baised application that should prevent the user if he tried to login three times with wrong password.

I will disable the login button for 10 minutes then I will enable it.

this is the interface

[image]

and this is the timer code

```
protected void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer--;
    if (timer == 0)
    {
        Button1.Enabled = true;
        Timer1.Enabled = false;
        Label1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

but when I run the application, after 10 minutes it's refresh the page without enable the login button

Comment: why do you name your login `button1` and not `login_button`? also, for testing, you should probably change the count to 15 seconds or so.

Comment: Am not expert in web applications. How'll you prevent user from taking a new login page? There button will be enabled I suppose?

Comment: don't worry about the names. I will refactor all the code, but i'm asking now about the logic. Thanks

Comment: What type of `Timer` are you using? [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [System.Threading.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a [`System.Tmers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then simply call:

```
Timer1.Start();
```

If you are using a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then this should start immediately. The third argument in the constructor is the `dueTime` which is:

> The amount of time to delay before callback is invoked, in milliseconds. Specify Timeout.Infinite to prevent the timer from starting. Specify zero (0) to start the timer immediately.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x96zfy7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So if this is non-zero your timer wont fire for the first time until after both the `dueTime` and `period` have elapsed. So if you have:

```
var timer1 = new Timer(callback, state, 10000, 10000);
```

the first time this will fire will be after 20 seconds and then it will fire every 10 seconds thereafter. If you want it to fire every 10 seconds then you need to specify 0 as the `dueTime`:

```
var timer1 = new Timer(callback, state, 0, 10000);
```